# MySQL Server issue -- keeps self-destructing

Tags: mysql

It's happened twice now, the first time I assumed it was because my computer crashed during an import and corrupted something in the process, but it just did it again. I'm importing a sizable (but still not massive) amount of data (100GB~) and around 10GB (both times), is when it failed and I was unable to restart the server no matter what I tried and I had to ultimately reimport the data.

The error:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

I'm running 5.7.21 on MacOS installed via Homebrew. Is there some setting I need to tweak for larger databases?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on MySQL Databases, but I wouldn't be surprised if you were hitting a wall when importing >4GB of data because one or multiple components of your DB is 32bit.

If you happen to have 64bit versions of said components, it might prevent the server from crashing.

I suggest you provide a more complete log of the import process, if available, to pinpoint where the crash might have occurred.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm pulling rows from excel docs and just inserting them into the table. and auto incrementing an item id field. I don't think there's anything wrong with the insert part as the first crash happened about twice as far into the process (the first failure happened on file 300, the second failure happened on file 180~). However, there was probably a similar amount of data in the database when the two failures occurred as there are numerous imports running now.

Comment: @st2tas  How much RAM does your server have?  Dedicated or Shared with other apps?  What version of MySQL?  OS?  Could you post text results (here or at pastebin.com) of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  if available, complete report from MySQLTuner.com software.  What was the size of the file to be imported in bytes?